# How can I make this code better? (C++ temperature converter)

Tags: c++

I wrote this temperature conversion program while practicing classes and functions in C++. While the code works, I am not entirely satisfied with it. 
Is there any way to make this code more efficient? Are there any 
persistent mistakes in my code?
I would love it if you would critique my code. Thanks.

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>

class convert{
public:
int c_con(float y){
float f;
    std::cout << "Converting to Fahrenheit: ";
    f=y*9/5+32;

    std::cout << f << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
int f_con(float x){
float c;
    std::cout << "Converting to Celsius:";
    c=(x-32)*5/9;

    std::cout << c << std::endl;
return 0;
}

};


int main(){
char a;
int b;
    convert temp;

    std::cout << "__________Temp Converter-----------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "What would like to convert? (c/f): ";
     std::cin >> a;

    switch(a)
    {
    case 'c' : std::cout << "Input Celsius: ";
           std::cin >> b;   
            temp.c_con(b);
            break;
    case 'f' :std::cout << "Input Fahrenheit: ";
              std::cin >> b;
                temp.f_con(b);
                break;
    default: std::cout << "Wrong input.";
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if there are no problems with your code.

Comment: Return something meaningful from the conversion functions (like the converted temperatures) and move the printing statements out of the conversion functions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on code-review but there isn't an option for that in the "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure others have better suggestions, but some very basic improvements are:

```
#include<iostream>
// Don't import libraries you don't use.

class Convert //Classes typically have the leading character Capitalized.
{
public:
    /*Give meaningful function names.*/
    float celsius_To_Fahrenheit(const float &y) /*Placing "const" in your parameters is good practice if you don't need/want to change the parameter inside the function.*/
    {
        //Try not to use local variables in classes, use member variables if you do need a variable.
        //I'm not sure either member function *needs* a local variable.
        //And I don't think this very simple classes needs local variables, yet.
        return y*9/5+32; /*Use "return" to return *something* otherwise, use "void" functions.*/
    }

    float fahrenheit_To_Celsius(const float &x)/*And using "&" to pass by reference is good in combination with "const", this makes your code more efficient so multiple copies don't exist of the same variable.*/
    {
        //Avoid putting std::cout statements inside classes as a habit.
        return (x-32)*5/9;
    }
};

int main()
{
    char choice = 'z'; //Give meaningful variable names.
    float temperature = 1; // Initialize local variables!
    Convert temp_converter;

    std::cout << "__________Temp Converter-----------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "What would like to convert? (c/f): ";
    std::cin >> choice;

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 'c' : std::cout << "Input Celsius: ";
            std::cin >> temperature;
            std::cout << temperature << " converted to Fahrenheit is " << temp_converter. celsius_To_Fahrenheit(temperature) << std::endl;
            break;
        case 'f' :std::cout << "Input Fahrenheit: ";
            std::cin >> temperature;
            std::cout << temperature << " converted to Celcius is " << temp_converter. fahrenheit_To_Celsius(temperature) << std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Wrong input.";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And if you _do_ use local variables, don't leave them uninitialized. You have a potential bug if `float f; /* ... other code ... */ f = 1;` accidentally uses `f` before the assignment, it is safer to have `float f = 1;`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

I won't post a wall of code as @NonCreature0714 has already done that.

I wouldn't have a class called `convert`. Will you stick `volt_amperes` and `watts` in there too?

Also what happens if you have a whole lot of functions that use Celsius and and another load that use Fahrenheit would they all live together in the same class?  Personally I would have a code unit called `celsius` and another code unit called `fahrenheit` and then have a third unit called `celsius_fahrenheit` which would handle conversions between the two.  This means you can have code that needs just Celsius without pulling in all the Fahrenheit.